# Jquery mobile list of methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am looking for a list of available methods for jQM. When I am trying to create a mobile site or native app, I need to know what I can use. For example is the .ajax method or the .load method included in the jQM framework (just an example not my question)

My overall goal is to know what my capabilities are so I can decide if I just use jQuery or jQM.

Thanks,
Mitch

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/  It is right on the website you downloaded it from.. .load and .ajax do completely different things.. they are based on the same but used differently. First learn jQuery.com

Comment: jQuery Mobile requires jQuery, therefore you can use all of the jQuery methods when using jQuery Mobile. For documentation on jQuery Mobile, visit http://jquerymobile.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about Jquery Mobile in the same way you think about JqueryUI, you still have all the .ajax and what not from regular Jquery, but you bring in more features and UI related stuff with JqueryMobile

See

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/